# Look for telephone that has called more than once in last 30 days

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI, I am trying to create a formula that shows where a telephone called more than once in 30 days.

I have a table that shows following:

- Originator (This is telephone)
- Orginator Time (Time the call came in)

I need to see if there were any repeat callers within that 30 days and if they called more than once, highlight a value such as 1 call this month, 2 calls this month, 3 calls this month etc.

I also want to create some conditional formatting that shows where someone has called 10> times in 30 days and is highlighted as red?

Comment: Basically what I want is to show where a telephone number has appeared more than once in 30 days and flag it as 1 call, 2nd call etc.

Comment: Rolling 30 days, or per month?

Comment: per month @Pieter

Comment: Just each month at a time @Pieter

Answer (score 0):

Oh, in that case, you'd want to create a Calendar table. Then it's just stupid easy.

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
CALENDAR(MINX('FactTable',[DateColumn]),MAXX('FactTable',[DateColumn]).
"Year", YEAR([Date]),
"MonthNumber", MONTH([Date]),
"MonthYear", DATE(YEAR([Date]),MONTH([Date]),1)
)
```

(That's a super small calendar... you can add columns for Week etc)

So once you have this, you join it to your fact table on the date column (If you have a date and a time, create a separate column for just the date, and one for just the time). Then you can just create simple measure, like COUNTROWS('FactTable'), and then drop the measure into the Values well and put the MonthYear on Rows, and you're sorted.

Then